# How to set max_nesting_level without using xdebug?

Tags: php, nested, xdebug, production-environment

The problem is, I want my production server to throw an error to https://sentry.io/ if there is an error because of nesting level more than x step. We had incident recently and it took us a few days to investigate, finally we found out that one segment of the code causes an infinity loop.

I took a few hours to look on the internet but so far I found the solution that involve xdebug (using xdebug.max_nesting_level variable) and I don't want to enable that on my production server because it will slow down the request.

Does anyone know how to limit max_nesting_level without using xdebug? Other idea is welcome too :)

Comment: I think there is no option like that. You can add a loop counter or something like that. Try to avoid loops, where you dont have any glue if they are terminating or not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions :)